# Python pandas apply function on columns value (base on columns names patern)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-munging

I have a dataframe:

```
a b  val1_b1 val1_b2 val2_b1 val2_v2
1 2    5       9        4      6
```

I want to take the max by column group, so the dataframe will be:

```
a b  val1  val2 
1 2    9     6
```

or the RMS:

```
a b       val1    val2
1 2    sqrt(106)   sqrt(52)
```

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: So if use `max` why is output `5` and `4` ? Why is `_v2` in last column name? Why is `106` and `52` in last `df` ?

Comment: @jezrael sorry the post was messed uo for some reason, I edit now a fix

Comment: For second `RMS` is necessary actual and predicted columns, not sure what columns are in input data.

Comment: @jezrael Great, max is working but not sure what do you mean and how to apply the RMS?

Comment: I think `rms` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47914428/python-dataframe-calculating-r2-and-rmse-using-groupby-on-one-column) - what columns are necessary use in your sample data.

Comment: @jezrael I meant RMS not RMSE - meaning sqrt(val1_b1^2  + val1_b2^2)

Comment: Thank you, added to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `max` with [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by columns, `axis=1` and lambda function fors values before first `_` (if exist):

```
df1 = df.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).max()
print (df1)
   a  b  val1  val2
0  1  2     9     6
```

EDIT for `RMS` use:

```
df2 = df.iloc[:, :2]
df3 = df.iloc[:, 2:].pow(2).groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1).sum().pow(1./2)

#alternative
df3 = (df.iloc[:, 2:].groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)
         .apply(lambda a: pd.Series(np.linalg.norm(a))))

df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1)
print (df4)

   a  b      val1      val2
0  1  2  10.29563  7.211103
```